OLS linear regression of +/-1 standard deviation and not the mean
I am sure that I am missing some of the nuances ... I know that OLS linear regression can be used to determine how the mean of the observed data $y$ depends on the independent data $x$. I also know that quantile regression minimizes absolute deviations, as opposed to the squared deviations of OLS, can be be used to determine how the median of $y$ depends on $x$. If I go further and weigh positive and negative deviations differently, quantile regression can determine how a particular quantile/percentile of $y$ depends on $x$. In my case, I am using quantile regression to estimate a 5th percentile cutoff for defining a normal/abnormal boundary for observations of $y$ given $x$.
Is there an equivalent weighting that allows to determine how the $1.64\sigma$ of $y$ depends on $x$?
I am looking to establish a cut off on a screening test where we can afford to send approximately 5% of the people screened for further evaluation. Right now the cutoff is the 5th percentile of $y$ calculated from 100k observations of $y$ while ignoring $x$. We know $y$ depends on $x$ and the quantile regression at the 5th and 50th percentile are different but the regression at the 50th percentile is about the same as the OLS regression. I want to improve the cutoff by using $x$.

Viewing +1.64$\sigma$ as equivalent to the the 95th percentile makes me think you're assuming normality of errors. Are you?

@TerenceC I am not sure what I am assuming yet. My gut is telling me that whenever regressing to a particular standard deviation might make sense, it would be better to use quantile regression.

I suspect that there might be a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal than using quantile regression or trying "to determine how the 1.64 of  depends on ." Consider editing the question to say more about what  and  mean in your data, whether there are any other variables that might be involved, and why you are trying to define a normal/abnormal boundary for values of  given . For example, why do you think that anything beyond the 95th percentile is an actual "abnormal" value rather than just a case at the extreme of the distribution of normal values?

@EdM see my edits.

Note that to compute the median of a normal distribution, OLS is more accurate than quantile regression.

"but the regression at the 50th percentile is about the same as the OLS regression." I don't understand the use of but. It suggests that there is something wrong.

If the linear regression model is $y|X \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2)$, then you can also compute estimates of quantiles by filling in estimates $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$.
In the case of estimating the median, then for normal distributed data the sample mean (or least squares) is a better estimator than the sample median (or least absolute residuals). In another question I guess that this is also true for other quantiles:  Minimum-variance unbiased estimator to estimate quantiles when the errors are normal distributed
You use quantile regression as a more robust estimator, when the error distribution is not a Gaussian distribution, and/or when the median and the mean do not coincide. In the case of non-normal distributed error terms, but still good estimates with the mean, you could also use the distribution of the residuals to compute quantiles, but this requires the assumption of homoscedasticity.
